# Determine if session cookies are enabled with ZF2

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2

Is there an easy way to determine if session cookies are enabled with ZF2?

I'm using `Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService` to log in users in my ZF2 application. When I call the `authenticate()` method, I get a valid result and the identity is set (`$result->isValid() == true` and `$result->getIdentity()` returns the identity). I then route to another action and the identity is lost if cookies are disabled. I don't get any exceptions and I don't know how to test whether the identity has been successfully stored in the session right after calling `authenticate()`. I only find out in the next request that the identity has been lost, which makes it more difficult to handle.

Comment: Please post your action code.

Comment: _“I only find out in the next request”_ – that is of course in general the case with cookies. You _can_ only find out with the next request if the cookie does get send back by the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, there's no way to check just after setting a cookie, the only thing you can do is see if the cookies exists on a subsequent request. This shouldn't be a common problem though, very few users disable cookies completely, and those that do will have issues on a number of sites.

One thing I did on a past project was add a query string parameter to the URL I redirected the user to after login - something like `?justLoggedIn=1`. Then, if this parameter is present, the app knows that the user *should* be logged in, so checks for the cookie. If it doesn't exist, it redirects the user again to a user-friendly "it looks like you have cookies disabled..." page with some help.